# Starting redis-server on Ubuntu EC2 with fabric

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, redis, fabric

Trying to do the above.

```
fab.sudo("redis-server")
```

I can see redis-server has started, but the fabric command line doesn't return for me to enter further commands. Suspect this is due to redis-server opening a terminal in default model. So:

```
fab.sudo("redis-server", pty=False)
```

No luck; same result; so

[confirmed that redis.conf has 'daemonize yes' set]

```
fab.sudo("nohup redis-server &> nohup.out")
```

No luck; same result.

:-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just [compiled](http://redis.io/topics/quickstart) Redis from source on an Ubuntu EC2 box and ran this Fab task:

```
def run_redis_server():
    with cd('~/redis-stable'):
        run("./src/redis-server")
```

where `redis-stable` is the Redis directory. 


It started the server successfully. Opening a shell `run("./src/redis-cli")` works as well.

Answer (score 0):

`redis-server` is started automatically when you `apt-get install redis-server`. Additionally, it installs an init script to start the server in daemon-mode (backgrounded). Try executing '`service redis-server start`', but this will require root access on most systems.